# Python Win32 - DriveInfo On Mapped Drive

Tags: python, winapi

Does anyone know how I can determine the server and share name of a mapped network drive?

For example:

```
import win32file, win32api
for logDrive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split("\x00"):
  if win32file.GetDriveType(logDrive) != win32file.DRIVE_REMOTE: continue
  # get server and share name here
```

Is there a  handy api call for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call the win32 API: [WNetGetUniversalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385474(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Brian, works perfectly and would have taken me forever to find that API call.